# Does $\left(\prod_iM_i\right)/\left(\prod_iS_i\right)\cong \prod_{i\in I}\left(M_i/S_i\right)$ hold for modules?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, direct-product

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ a family of $R$-modules and $\{S_i\subseteq M_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $R$-submodules.   Does the following hold true $$\left(\prod_iM_i\right)/\left(\prod_iS_i\right)\cong \prod_{i\in I}\left(M_i/S_i\right)?$$ Where $\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ is a direct product of modules.  Is there a documented **Reference in a Text Book/or Published Paper** for this isomorphism.

I have a reference for this isomorphism for direct summands in (Advanced Modern Algebra, Part 1 by Joseph J. Rotman (Proposition B-2.20)). That is, $$\left(\bigoplus_iM_i\right)/\left(\bigoplus_iS_i\right)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}\left(M_i/S_i\right).$$  However, I don't have any reference for direct products other than ([Modifying $\frac{\prod_\alpha A_\alpha}{\prod_\alpha B_\alpha}\simeq \prod_\alpha\frac{A_\alpha}{B_\alpha}$ for direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756066/modifying-frac-prod-alpha-a-alpha-prod-alpha-b-alpha-simeq-prod-alph?noredirect=1&lq=1))!

Comment: What is $M_ir$? By the wording looks like $M_ir$ is just a submodule of $M_i$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes $M_ir$ is $M_i\times r$ which is a submodule of $M_i$

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I mean, $M_ir$ has a definition? The $r$ makes something?

Comment: In general, for a right $R$-module $M$ and $r \in R$, $Mr$ is not necessarily a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the hypothesis that $R$ is commutative

Comment: Then, replace $M_ir$ with $rM_i$, as any right module over a commutative ring is also a left module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying $\frac{\prod_\alpha A_\alpha}{\prod_\alpha B_\alpha}\simeq \prod_\alpha\frac{A_\alpha}{B_\alpha}$ for direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756066/modifying-frac-prod-alpha-a-alpha-prod-alpha-b-alpha-simeq-prod-alph)

Comment: It partially answers my question. My only worry is that I want an authored book or paper for further reading and reference about this result.

Comment: Isn't this just a trivial application of the first isomorphism theorem?